# What are the gamma-Pareto convolutions and how have they been used?

Tags: gamma-distribution, convolution, pareto-distribution

The [Pareto distributions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParetoDistribution.html), i.e., density functions (pdf), are types I through IV and the type II variant; the Lomax distribution. This makes for a number of possible gamma-Pareto convolutions (GPC; also density functions). Of these the GPC type I and GPC Lomax have been used in the literature, at least in so far as I know. Let us start by defining the parameterizations used for GPC type I.

The gamma distribution (GD) can be given as

\begin{equation}\label{eq:GD}
 \text{GD}(a,b;t) =
 \,\dfrac{1}{t}\;\dfrac{e^{-b \, t}(b \, t)^{\,a} }{\Gamma (a)} \;\theta(t)\;,
\end{equation}

where the gamma function satisfies $\Gamma (a)=\int _0^{\infty } e^{-t} t^{a-1}\,dt$, and $\theta(t)$ is the unit step function, i.e., 0 for $t<0$ and 1 for $t\geq0$. The GD rate parameter is $b$, whereas $\frac{1}{b}$ is the scale parameter. The shape parameter for the GD is $a$. The shape parameter aids in fitting data and data shapes. There is no location parameter.

Next, we define a type I Pareto distribution ($\text{PD}_{\text{I}}$ a pdf),

\begin{equation}
\text{PD}_{\text{I}}(\alpha, \beta;t)=
 \dfrac{\alpha}{t}  \left(\dfrac{\beta}{t}\right) ^{\alpha }  \;\theta(t-\beta)\;.
\end{equation}

Note the shift to the right of the unit step function; $\theta(t-\beta)$, i.e., the PD function is zero for $t<\beta$. $\beta$ is the scale parameter. The shape parameter is $\alpha$. There is no location parameter.

The PD type II pdf is

$$\text{PD}_{\text{II}}(\alpha ,\beta ,\mu;t)=\frac{\beta  }{\alpha }\left(\frac{\alpha -\mu +t}{\alpha }\right)^{-\beta -1}\theta (t-\mu ). $$

The PD type II Lomax pdf is

$$\text{PD}_{\text{Lomax}}(\alpha ,\beta ,0;t)=\frac{\beta  }{\alpha }\left(\frac{\alpha +t}{\alpha }\right)^{-\beta -1}\theta (t ) .$$

The PD type III pdf is

$$\text{PD}_{\text{III}}(\alpha ,1,\gamma ,\mu;t)=\frac{\alpha ^{-1/\gamma } (t-\mu )^{\frac{1}{\gamma }-1}}{\gamma  \left[\left(\frac{\alpha }{t-\mu }\right)^{-1/\gamma }+1\right]^2}\theta (t-\mu ) .$$

The PD type IV pdf is

$$\text{PD}_{\text{IV}}(\alpha ,\beta,\gamma ,\mu;t)=\frac{\beta}{\gamma }  \alpha ^{-1/\gamma } (t-\mu )^{\frac{1}{\gamma }-1} \left[\left(\frac{\alpha }{t-\mu }\right)^{-1/\gamma }+1\right]^{-\beta -1}\theta (t-\mu ) .$$

The infinite series describing the GPC type I convolution is given in the answer below. There is no closed form solution. Such functions are computer implemented as truncated infinite series.

I will award a bounty to anyone who shows a solution$^\star$ for a GPC distribution type whose solution is not referenced here, i.e., GPC type II (non-Lomax), GPC type III or GPC type IV.

$^\star$EDIT: Any exact and calculable reformatting of any convolution integral of the form: $$\begin{align}\text{GPC}_j\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ 
\alpha &\beta
\end{array} \Big|\,t\right)&=\text{GD}(a,b;x)\ast\text{PD}_j(\alpha,\beta;x)\,(t)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{GD}(a,b;x-t)\,\text{PD}_{j}(\alpha,\beta,\,,\,;t) \;dt,\end{align}$$ 
where  $j=\text{II, III, or IV}$. I do not consider limiting discrete convolutions for $\Delta t\to0$, i.e., a limiting or Riemann sum of the convolution integral, to be exact solutions unless the limits sign can be removed in such a fashion as to provide a calculation of any desired accuracy.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "documents those ... types"?  What would constitute a "documentation" (listing of mathematical propertiess? potential applications? references?) and what specifically are the "types not listed here"?

Comment: @whuber I can, and did. Surprised I am that it was not clear from the context.

Comment: I cannot speak to the downvote, Carl, because I did not apply it, so please do not insinuate I did.  (I would be happy to prove I did not by applying one :-)  In general, please do not complain about downvotes: it's not constructive and can only antagonize people.  Returning to my previous comment: please explain what you mean by "documenting a solution to" one of these distributions.

Comment: @whuber I knew you did not do the downvote, I know you fairly well. I did not insunuate anything but wrote to you as a moderator saying that I do not like downvoting on well-formatted questions or even on poorly formatted ones, I do not think they serve any purpose that is not better accomplished else-wise. I removed the comment so no-one else can misinterpret it either. I do not understand your comment as to "what do I mean?" I am asking for convolutions written as formulas not containing a convolution operator. What is unclear to you?

Comment: For starters, I have yet to see any convolution operators in this thread!  I truly do not understand what you are going after in this question.  Are you trying to obtain formulas for densities (or CDFs or CFs or CGs or something) of sums of Gamma and Pareto variables?  And if so, what kind of formulas are wanted?  I notice the one in your answer is an infinite sum, which is less than convenient and in many ways less useful than the original convolution integral.

Comment: @whuber I start with density functions, AKA distributions, and the convolution of two density functions is a density function. The convolution operator $\ast$ is standard notation and appears in the answer below. One cannot use the convolution alone with any good speed. My implementation of the infinite sum in Mathematica has a run time of 0.025 s. I do not see how this can be done else-wise, so I do not understand your criticism. Even a sine function is implemented as an infinite series, accelerated no doubt, but a series executed by software none-the-less.

Comment: @whuber There are no closed form expressions for any GPC of which I am aware. A computer program is listed in the [Computer Networks](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1389128607000837) paper referenced for the Lomax GPC,; it is a double infinite series, and the GPC type I listed is less complicated than that.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking about computer implementations.  There are alternative mathematical definitions of sine, for instance, as the inverse of an integral or as an infinite product, that may lend themselves to effective computation; and often an integral is an excellent analytical tool. This takes us right back to the beginning: what exactly constitutes a "solution"?

Comment: @whuber Convolution is defined as an integral. A solution to a convolution integral has a format similar to invoking the Mathematica command [convolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Convolve.html). In this case, the Mathematica routine cannot be directly applied to the problem as it is beyond the range of complexity that Mathematica can handle. A solution to a convolution is an exact restatement of its integral.  A recursion solution to a convolution would be a solution, a restatement into closed forms would be a solution. Still not seeing what your objection is.

Comment: A *mathematical* "solution" to a convolution would be *any* way of expressing the resulting function. Your question appears focus on *a certain family of distributions.* A "solution" in that context could mean anything from explaining how the distribution arises in nature or mathematics to formulas for its moments, its CDF, it CG, etc. I'm not objecting to anything, but after requesting clarification from you four times I'm not getting much closer to understanding what would constitute a good or complete answer. I therefore feel it would not be worth any time or effort to contribute to one.

Comment: @whuber You state, "A "solution" in that context could mean anything..." Indeed, with the restriction that it be 1) exact and 2) calculable. From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/solution) 4. Mathematics: (a) The process of determining the answer to a problem. (b) The answer itself.

Comment: @whuber Yes, solutions can take many forms, and I do not care which is given as long as it is exact and calculable. I have provided the exact and calculable criteria for what constitutes a solution explicitly in the Q/A.

Comment: @whuber I have addressed your concerns. I note that the extent of clarity you demanded exceeds that in the peer reviewed publications cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GPC type I](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10928-019-09666-z) has been [open access published](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10928-019-09666-z.pdf) recently and used to model metformin drug serum concentrations following intravenous bolus injection. Derived from series expansion of the GD exponential above, followed by convolution with a PD, as above and summation of the expanded parts. The GPC type I model inherits two shape parameters, $a$ and $\alpha$, and two scale related parameters, $b\; (T^{-1})$ and $\beta\;(T)$ from its convolved pdf's,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{GPC}_{\text{I}}(t;a,b,\alpha,\beta)
 &=\text{GD}( x;a,b)\ast \text{PD}_{\text{I}}(x;\alpha , \beta) \;(t)\\
&=\theta (t-\beta) \frac{\alpha b^a\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma (a)}t^{a-\alpha-1}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-b\,t)^n}{n!}   B_{1-\frac{\beta}{t}}(a+n,-\alpha)
\end{split}\;\;,
\end{equation}

where the [incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) is $B_z(A,B)=\int _0^z u^{A-1} (1-u)^{B-1}d u$. Note that this is exact but is calculable by removing the limiting $\infty$ for $n$ as follows. Because the series is alternating, for $n>m$, where $m$ is some positive integer, no matter how large, the series sum thereafter has decreasing absolute error, as it then satisfies the [Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test), where the absolute error is less than the absolute magnitude of the $n>m^{\text{th}}$ term.

Proof: First note that $\lim_{t\to\infty}B_{1-\frac{\beta}{t}}(a+n,-\alpha)=B(a+n,-\alpha)$, where $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the beta function. Next, $\lim_{n\to\infty}B(a+n,-\alpha)=0$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}t^{a-\alpha-1}  \frac{(-b\,t)^n}{n!}=0$, no matter how large $t$. Finally, $0\cdot0=0$,  thus the $n^{\text{th}}$ term absolute value can be made smaller than $\epsilon$, no matter how small for $n$ sufficiently large.||

An alternative formulation is used for $t$-long, because the alternating term magnitude inflates as $t$ increases, requiring very high precision for use of the primary definition above. The alternate formula is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{GPC}_{\text{I}}(t;a,b,\alpha,\beta)=&-\theta (t-\beta) \frac{ \alpha b^a }{\Gamma (a)}t^{a-1}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{\beta }{t}\right)^k \frac{(1-a)_k}{k! (k-\alpha )} \, _1F_1(a,a-k;-b t)\\
&+\theta (t-\beta )\left[ \frac{b^a }{\Gamma (a)} e^{-b t} t^{a-1}-\pi \csc (\pi \alpha )\frac{b^a \beta ^{\alpha } }{\Gamma (\alpha )} t^{a-\alpha -1} \, _1\tilde{F}_1(a,a-\alpha ;-b t)\right]
\end{split}\;\;\;.
\end{equation}

The above is shown as Theorem 1 of [this paper](https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10928-021-09779-4).

The GPC Lomax distribution: [On the convolution of Pareto and gamma distributions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1389128607000837) was published in 2007 and is proposed for usage to determine inter arrival times between on-traffic (off-traffic) random variates. It is derived explicitly in that text in a fashion analogous to the GPC type I above, however, it was parameterized differently and to see it either [contact the authors](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222052624_On_the_convolution_of_Pareto_and_gamma_distributions) or download it from a library service.

Closed form expressions for GPC types I to IV may not be possible. However, by combining certain parameters and reducing their number by one parameter, closed form expressions for simplified GPC types II through IV can be [written](https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/jmasm/vol11/iss1/7/).